# Oracle view: how to obtain a column definition

Tags: oracle, view, definition

I have an Oracle view:

```
create view schemaName.viewName as
select case when 1=1 then 1 else 2 end as col1, decode('A','A','B','C') as col2 from dual
```

Is there a way to obtain an output or a table with this information:

```
Column_Name: Col1
Column_Definition: case when 1=1 then 1 else 2 end

Column_Name: Col2
Column_Definition: decode('A','A','B','C')
```

Thank you very much

Comment: I do not think there is any way to do that.

Comment: Oracle can tell you the view column names and data types, but the definition of column is not available. It would be very hard to achieve, as there may be no simple column definition in the query backing the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the below anonymous block to get column name and column definition for above view.

      DECLARE

      a varchar2(1000);
      b varchar2(1000);
      c varchar2(1000);

      BEGIN

      EXECUTE  IMMEDIATE 'SELECT TEXT FROM user_views
      WHERE VIEW_NAME=''TEST_VW'' ' INTO a;

      SELECT  regexp_replace(regexp_substr(a, '^[^,]*'),'select|as\W','') -- getting first argument case to get "case when 1=1 then 1 else 2 end col1"

      into b from dual;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Column_Name: '|| regexp_substr(b,'[^ ]+$')); -- this command to get last col1 from "case when 1=1 then 1 else 2 end col1"

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Column_Definition: '|| regexp_replace(b,'[^ ]+$','')); -- this command to make col1 to empty to get column definition

      select  regexp_replace(substr(a,length(regexp_substr(a, '^[^,]*'))+2),'select|dual|from|as\W','') into c from dual; -- this command to get 2nd column "decode('A','A','B','C') col2"


      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Column_Name: '||  REGEXP_SUBSTR ( c , '[^ ]+' , 1 , 2 )); -- This command will get 2nd column col2 from "decode('A','A','B','C') col2"

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Column_Definition: '||  REGEXP_SUBSTR ( c , '[^ ]+' , 1 , 1 ));  -- This command will get 1st column decode('A','A','B','C') from "decode('A','A','B','C') col2"

      END;
```

Comment: My query is only an example, I need this for every possible oracle view and there is no fixed columns. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks for clarifying ... just try below block and see if this helps ..Also let me know for any column definition which is incorrect

prerequiste for ananymous block:

create view TEST_VW as
select case when 1=1 then 1 else 2 end as col1, decode('A','A','B','C') as col2, 
null as col3 , sysdate as col4 , 'var1' as col5  
from dual;
```

-- In view definition I hope a format of each column as  and  separator of each columns is key to separate the column name and definition for this block.

```
 create sequence seq
      start with 1;

create table col_nm_def 
      (column_nm varchar2(1000),
      column_def varchar2(1000),
      id number);


Ananymous block;

DECLARE 

      a varchar2(1000); 
      b varchar2(1000); 
      c varchar2(1000);
      d number;

      BEGIN 

      EXECUTE  IMMEDIATE 'SELECT TEXT FROM user_views 
      WHERE VIEW_NAME=''TEST_VW'' ' INTO a;

       EXECUTE  IMMEDIATE 'delete from col_nm_def';

       EXECUTE  IMMEDIATE  'drop sequence seq';


       EXECUTE  IMMEDIATE     'create sequence seq
      start with 1';


      select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(a,'select|from|dual',''),'as\W|, ' , '|') into b from dual; -- replacing as and (, ) to | symbol (try to change symbol if view uses this pipe in transformation)

      select regexp_count(b,'[|]') into d from dual; 

      d:=d+1;

      For i in 1..d

      LOOP

      insert into col_nm_def  values (REGEXP_SUBSTR ( b , '[^|]+' , i+1 , i+1 ),REGEXP_SUBSTR ( b , '[^|]+' , i , i ),seq.nextval);
      COMMIT;

    END LOOP;
    END;


Final result : select only odd rows 

select * from col_nm_def where mod(id,2)=1 order by ID;
```